# Local Storage APIs do not work within NativeScript WebView

Tags: android, local-storage, nativescript

My application is a web app hosted within a {N} WebView. The username & password are store in the localStore. When I leave the app and re-enter I do not have data and I have to go back to login.

Could someone help me? or explain how to debug a web view in an app.
the webpage is developed with Angular 4 and the app with NativeScript.

Comment: Why would you store passwords in localStorage?

Comment: to be able to use the same login method on both web and mobile. I use it so that the user does not have to enter the password constantly.Can you think of a way to do the same login for the web and the app? Thank you

Comment: You should store the sessionId or whatever you use verifies that the session is valid. ANYONE that helps you with this problem could easily hack your site and steal all your users data. Do NOT continue with this method.

Answer (score 4):

With Android `localStorage` APIs won't work until you enable them. You could enable it by accessing the native WebView's settings upon loaded event.

```
export function onWebViewLoaded(args) {
    const webView = args.object;
    if (webView.android) {
        webView.android.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=DbiXe8)

Between, whether you can `localStorage` for saving confidential informations such as username / password is a different question here. My answer will be no, you can't use it as it's easy / open to access. Generally you should hit the login api with these credentials given by user, you should probably get `access token` which you will use for any communication with server subsequently. You could store this token in your `localStoage`, clear it upon logout.

Comment: Please don't help this developer create a huge security risk to his site.

Comment: may you explain a bit about that risk? I found that this solution works for me, but I don't want to have security problems

Comment: @Noark I know I'm late, but I believe Mickers is talking about the insecurity of the OP's method of authentication (he says he's storing passwords directly in localStorage). He's not talking about any inherent insecurities with NativeScript or localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect, thanks!!
the example works well.

.html

```
<Page (loaded)="pageLoaded($event)">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
           <WebView  #myWebView [src]="webViewSrc" (loadStarted)="onWebViewLoadStarted($event)"></WebView>
        </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

-component(ts file)

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls:['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent  {
   public webViewSrc: string = URL;
    constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    onWebViewLoaded(args){
        const webView = args.object;
        if (webView.android) {
            webView.android.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.android.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        }
    }
    pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
        let page = <Page>args.object;
        page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't help this developer create a huge security risk to his site.