# How do I enable LocalStorage in a Nativescript Vue WebView?

Tags: android, webview, local-storage, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a `WebView` in my Nativscript Vue app but on Android, the embedded website does not have access to localStorage within the browser. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576832/local-storage-apis-do-not-work-within-nativescript-webview/54578109#54578109) explains how to do it for Angular. The problem was that it was unclear where the webview instance was supposed to be gotten from. Question for completeness: How do I access the WebView instance that contains the `android` property in order to enable local storage on it?

Comment: You can of course add `loaded` listener and access  `webView.android` in Vue. It's not a limitation for Vue.

Comment: Sorry @douira, may be you could try asking better or in a different way. The other SO thread you have linked already shows how exactly it could be enabled on Android. As I already mentioned Vue still supports all those events and native objects. So if you say you can't make it work with your Vue component, at least you should justify why.

Comment: I've clarified it now and answered with my solution. Please reconsider how bad this question was vs how it is now.

Comment: `loadFinished` event is triggered on every page navigation within WebView. Using loaded event saves it, you just have to do it once for WebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it in the end. I needed to access the WebView passed through the event handler in the property `event.object`. There is no event called `onWebViewLoaded` on the component since this is not Angular. Instead, we need to hook onto the `loadFinished` event on the `WebView` element.

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <WebView
      src="https://www.example.com/"
      @loaded="onLoaded"
    />
  </Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    //when the webview finishes loading
    onLoaded(event) {
      //get the webview
      const webView = event.object

      //if there is android
      if (webView.android) {
        //enable dom storage in the webview on android
        webView.android.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use Vuex combined with this plugin [nativescript-localstorage](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage).
I say it's untested on Nativescript 6. I can say it works because I use it my self.

Example of the `store.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import localStorage from 'nativescript-localstorage';

const NSVuexPersistent = store => {
    let storageStr = localStorage.getItem('ns-vuex-persistent');
    if (storageStr) {
        store.replaceState(JSON.parse(storageStr))
    }
    store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        // Suscribe hook.
        localStorage.setItem('ns-vuex-persistent', JSON.stringify(state));
    })
};

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        nations: null
    },
    plugins: [NSVuexPersistent],
    mutations: {
        updateNations(state, nations) {
            state.nations= nations;
        }
    }
});
```

How does your `main.js` looks (add this):

```
import store from './store';

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start()
```

Comment: this does not address the problem in any way. I'm asking about how to enable localStorage for a webView not how to persist nativescript state.

Comment: My fault. I misread your question. Like @Manoj said: So if you say you can't make it work with your Vue component, at least you should justify why.